# How update APi with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I create a simple single page application with angularJS and laravel , , the method get, delete and store created , now how create the update method in my code?
I use below link in my app
https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'],function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

app.factory('Depot', function($http) {
return {
    get : function() {
        return $http.get('depots/depot');
    },

    save : function(commentData) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'depots/depot',
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: $.param(commentData)
        });
    },

    destroy : function(depot_number) {
        return $http.delete('depots/depot/' + depot_number);
    }


}

});

 app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http, Depot) {
$scope.commentData = {};

$('#show_success').hide();
$('#show_remove').hide();


Depot.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.comments = data;
    });


$scope.submitComment = function() {
    Depot.save($scope.commentData)
        .success(function(data) {
            Depot.get()
                .success(function(getData) {
                        $('#add_depot').hide();
                        $('#depot_name').val('');
                        $('#have_id').removeAttr('checked');
                        $('#show_success').show();
                         setTimeout(function() {
                             $('#show_success').hide();
                         },1500);
                   $scope.comments = getData;
                });
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
};


$scope.deleteComment = function(id) {
    Depot.destroy(id)
        .success(function(data) {
            Depot.get()
                .success(function(getData) {
                    $('#show_remove').show();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#show_remove').hide();
                    },1500);
                    $scope.comments = getData;
                });
        });
};

 });
```

Comment: Would you please add the Laravel code that you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on the documentation for [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). This is by far your best bet for a RESTful application.

I have answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024853/what-is-the-best-approach-for-integrating-angularjs-with-a-non-restful-api/34025411#34025411) a *bit* more detailed, perhaps it could help you too?
We really do need your endpoints / server-code to help you more.